# Does the Flixbus N770 from Antwerp to Copenhagen go by ferry to Denmark

Tags: germany, denmark, flixbus

Tonight I am catching the N770 Flixbus from Antwerp to Copenhagen. Apparently it doesn't stop between Eindhoven and Copenhagen. Do the night Flixbuses to Denmark typically go via Puttgarden-Rødby, requiring passengers to step out on the ferry, or can I expect to sleep through the night?

Answer (score 18):

The FlixBuses to Denmark from Germany do indeed *generally** take a ferry from Puttgarden to Rödby.

The ferry departs [every 30 minutes](https://www.scandlines.com/tickets-und-tarife/fahrplane) and there is a passport control so you have no option sleeping through.

Once on the ferry you are required to leave the bus. You can sleep in various places on the boat but keep in mind that the driver will not wait for you - immediately go to the bus when such instructions are announced, about 5 minutes before arrival.

---

**Changes in traffic could cause the bus to take another route. This could for example be ferry departures, accidents, weather etc.*

Comment: According to https://www.scandlines.com/tickets-und-tarife/fahrplane, the ferry departs every 30 minutes.

Comment: Not really important but keep in mind "Change of schedule until 06.10.2019 at 07:00 there will be a departure every 40 minutes. Thereafter we resume the regular schedule with departures every 30 minutes. We apologise for any inconvenience. Current traffic information can be found at www.scandlines.com. Best regards, Scandlines"

Comment: Why would there be passport control?

Comment: @JonathanReez looking at [the map](https://maps.app.goo.gl/zAGQYWJY7zekXXed8) indeed there doesn't seem to be any border police stations at either side...

Comment: @JonathanReez that's a good question for the Danish authorities, but it is indeed standard procedure that there's an immigration check on arrival in Denmark via this route.

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder I last took this ferry about two months ago, I can confirm the presence of immigration checks on arrival in Denmark. They boarded the bus shortly after we left the ferry, I'm not entirely sure but I think it was near the white-roofed structure over the road which can be seen on the way out of the port at Rødby.

Comment: As an aside: while the immigration control on arrival in Rødby is standard procedure, it isn't necessarily taken particularly seriously. On my last trip (also via Flixbus) the passenger behind me had no ID documents, but was nevertheless allowed in with nothing other than a firm reminder to bring a passport or ID card next time. Of course, that's no guarantee that other officers will be so lenient.

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder Apparently not correct for this particular line - it crossed the border at Padborg in Jutland.

Comment: @JonathanReez Denmark has temporarily re-introduced border controls (probably due to the migrant crisis, though the official explanation is "severe threat to public order and internal security"). It currently applies to the "internal border with Germany (land and ports with ferry connections); may extend to all internal borders", and is currently valid until 12 November 2019. https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/schengen/reintroduction-border-control_en

Comment: @ToivoSäwén maybe because of the change in schedule for the Puttgarden ferry.

Answer (score 10):

**It may not.**

Apparently (at least tonight) the N770 line Paris-Copenhagen in particular does **not take the ferry route** via Puttgarden-Rødby, but rather crossed the Danish border at Padborg in Jutland. There was indeed a quick passport control there around 5 AM, but there was no need to exit the bus.

Comment: The correct answer is probably 'maybe, maybe not'. The bus does not have any scheduled stops between Eindhoven and Copenahgen and must not follow a predetermined route. There is not much difference in the driving time between the two route options and I can even imagine that the bus drivers may decide on a case-by-case basis which route to take. Road works and anticipated waiting times for the ferry may change from day to day which route is assumably faster.